# Manhwa where the MC is a college student who gets an orb that's a portal to another world and travels back and forth, also building a doomsday car

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The manhwa starts with a college student staying back in college to work part time and then has a weird portal orb crashed into his room. He can go to another world with this portal and then gets a mission to take over a village and the village is overthrown by mercenaries. Time stops in either world when the portal is closed. So the main character goes back to Earth and builds a *Death Race* kinda car with spikes and blades that the locals mistake for a "Hades chariot".  He then spins a wheel and saves a valkyrie.

It's just 22 chapters or so.